# SQLAlchemy Get All Rows For Column Combination

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using Flask-SQLAlchemy (but willing to drop to SQLAlchemy if needed) and trying to get figure out a way to get all values from a table where a combination of 4 columns are unique.

For example, I have this object Class -

```py
class SearchRule(db.Model):
  id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
  type = db.Column(db.Text)
  location = db.Column(db.Text)
  owner = db.Column(db.Text)
  delegate = db.Column(db.Text)
  set_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('set.id'))
```

What I'd like to return is all `set_id` values where a combination of `type + location + owner + delegate` are unique.

Here is an example table -

```
id    type    location    owner    delegate    set_id
1     db      usa         matt     joe         5
2     db      usa         matt     joe         6
3     db      uk          jim      bob         9
4     db      uk          jim      bob         12
```

From this table I would like to return something like the following -

```
[
  ('db', 'usa', 'matt', 'joe', [5, 6]), 
  ('db', 'uk, 'jim', 'bob', [9, 12])
]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why wouldn't a group by work here. Group by will get you distinct values of the columns by whats being group and then applying distinct to the aggregated column will get you distinct values of the ids. If you want all values of the ids just omit the `distinct()`

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import func

query = session.query.(SearchRule.type, SearchRule.location,
                           SearchRule.owner, SearchRule.delegate, 
                           func.group_concat(SearchRule.set_id.distinct())/
               .group_by(SearchRule.type, SearchRule.location,
                         SearchRule.owner, SearchRule.delegate)
```

`group_concat` will produce a comma joined string which you should be able to convert to whatever you need in the python code

Answer (score 0):

The query you need to run is:

```
session.query(SearchRule.type, SearchRule.location, 
              SearchRule.owner, SearchRule.delegate).distinct()
```

The result of this query with your data is:

```
('db', 'usa', 'matt', 'joe')
('db', 'uk', 'jim', 'bob')
```

To get the list of set-ids, one needs to use group-concat:

```
session.query(SearchRule.type, SearchRule.location, 
            SearchRule.owner, SearchRule.delegate, func.group_concat(SearchRule.set_id)).group_by(SearchRule.type, 
            SearchRule.location, SearchRule.owner, SearchRule.delegate)
```

The result is:

```
('db', 'uk', 'jim', 'bob', '9,12')
('db', 'usa', 'matt', 'joe', '5,6')
```

Comment: That is as far as I got too, but is there a way to include a list of the `set_id` that match that 4-column combination in the result as well?